# I want index.php to access files restricted by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't have code to show you because none of mine really work but I need to know how restrict files (`jpgs` and `php`) in my `upload` folder located in my root (`root/upload/`). I want to make it so if you go to `mysite.com/upload/` then nothing appears but I want my `index.php` located in my root (`root/index.php`) to be able to access the jpgs and php in the restricted `upload/` folder. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
index.php

/uploads/ 

/uploads/temp/

/uploads/temp/upload.php 

/uploads/temp/.htaccess 

/uploads/temp/(multiple jpeg files)
```

I want it so that if you go to mysite.com/uploads/temp then nothing pops up but I want the `index.php` to be able to call the `images` and `upload.php`

Comment: You say php within your uploads folder, how are you using the php files?, easiest option would be to add a `.htaccess` within the uploads folder with `deny from all` in it and then load the images through a php script.

Comment: By "able to access the jpgs and php" do you mean read the file from the physical file system, or do you mean *refer* to the jpgs and php files via linking from the page's content?

Comment: Heres whwats in the root:

Comment: index.php
uploads/

uploads/temp/

uploads/temp/upload.php
uploads/temp/.htaccess
uploads/temp/(multiple jpeg files)

i want it so that if you go to mysite.com/uploads/temp then nothing pops up but i want the index.php to be able to call the images and upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice in your `.htaccess`. Just drop it into the `upload` directory.

```
# Refuse direct access to all files
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Are there any issues with `X-Forwarded-For` spoofing here?

Comment: it didn't work if it helps im hosting my site on 000webhost.com

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `uploads/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block if referrer is not your domain's index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com/index\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```